SQL count occurrences based on values in other columns
I'm using SQL Server to query some data. Here is what that data looks like:



ID
AssignedLevel
ManLevel02ID
ManLevel03ID
ManLevel04ID
ManLevel05ID
OrgCount




11111
1




2


22222
2
11111
44444
55555
66666
1


33333
3
11111
22222
55555
66666
0



In this example I am trying to come up with the values in the column named OrgCount. The AssignedLevel + 1 tells me what ManLevel column to look at. So for the first row, ID 11111, their assigned level is 1 meaning I need to count values in the column ManLevel02ID that match the ID.
I'm trying to get this to work.
SELECT
    [ID],
    [AssignedLevel],
    [ManLevel02ID],
    [ManLevel03ID],
    [ManLevel04ID],
    [ManLevel05ID],
    CASE
        WHEN ([AssignedLevel] + 1) = 2 
            THEN SUM(CASE WHEN [ManLevel02ID] = [ID] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN ([AssignedLevel] + 1) = 3 
            THEN SUM(CASE WHEN [ManLevel03ID] = [ID] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN ([AssignedLevel] + 1) = 4 
            THEN SUM(CASE WHEN [ManLevel04ID] = [ID] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN ([AssignedLevel] + 1) = 5 
            THEN SUM(CASE WHEN [ManLevel05ID] = [ID] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        ELSE 0
    END AS [OrgCount]
FROM 
    EmpTable

This is not working for me and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Why [AssignedLevel] + 1, what purpose has this calculation?

AssignedLevel is currently off by 1. This is a temporary fix until they fix it on the dataset itself.

I modified the question to account for this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Don't think you can avoid a self-join:
select *
into #data
from (
    VALUES  (11111, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2)
    ,   (22222, 2, 11111, 44444, 55555, 66666, 1)
    ,   (33333, 3, 11111, 22222, 55555, 66666, 0)
) t (ID,AssignedLevel,ManLevel02ID,ManLevel03ID,ManLevel04ID,ManLevel05ID,OrgCount)

select d.AssignedLevel, d.ID, d.ManLevel02ID, d.ManLevel03ID, d.ManLevel04ID, d.ManLevel05ID
, COUNT(d2.ID) AS OrgCount
from #data d
left join #data d2
    ON  d.ID = CASE d.AssignedLevel WHEN 1 THEN d2.ManLevel02ID WHEN 2 THEN d2.ManLevel03ID WHEN 3 THEN d2.ManLevel04ID WHEN 4 THEN d2.ManLevel05ID END
GROUP BY d.AssignedLevel, d.ID, d.ManLevel02ID, d.ManLevel03ID, d.ManLevel04ID, d.ManLevel05ID

This joins main table with itself based on your logic of AssignedLevel and then aggregates the available IDs into a COUNT.
Note that this structure isn't great to best honest, and the query will be slow if you have a lot of rows, but yeah, that's the general idea.
Edit, here's another solution based on temporary data storage:
select  x.ID, x.level, COUNT(*) AS cnt
into    #aggdata
from #data d
cross apply (
    values  (1, ManLevel02ID)
    ,   (2, ManLevel03ID)
    ,   (3, ManLevel04ID)
    ,   (4, ManLevel05ID)
    ) x (level, ID)
GROUP BY x.ID, x.level

create unique clustered index IX_agg_data_main ON #aggdata (ID, level)

select d.AssignedLevel, d.ID, d.ManLevel02ID, d.ManLevel03ID, d.ManLevel04ID, d.ManLevel05ID
, ISNULL(d2.cnt, 0) AS OrgCount
from #data d
left join #aggdata d2
    ON  d2.ID = d.ID
    AND d2.level = d.AssignedLevel

Output:



AssignedLevel
ID
ManLevel02ID
ManLevel03ID
ManLevel04ID
ManLevel05ID
OrgCount




1
11111
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2


2
22222
11111
44444
55555
66666
1


3
33333
11111
22222
55555
66666
0




This worked. Unfortunately, I do have a lot of rows and this took quite a while. Do you think there are other, quicker, methods or is this pretty much it?

Dunno if it will be faster but you could gather all IDs grouped by level into a #temp-table and then join against it from the main table, it will be two steps, but perhaps indexes will improve the perf

Got it. Thanks.

Another question if you don't mind. Would it be better if we looped through each ManLevel column instead of relying on AssignedLevel? I would think no, because that column helps avoid having to loop, right?

If one have to look on all levels, I'd probably just unpivot the level IDs into a single row and then join it, no need to loop.

Would it make it faster by doing that or no?

It's easier for you to test than for me, i don't have access to your data. You also didn't include any index information, which makes it even harder to guess

Ok. Originally, my post said I was relatively new to SQL but someone edited that out. I'll figure that out. I have no idea what you mean by index but I'll look into it and test things out. Thanks for your help.

I added another solution as example to play around with. It unpivots the data and pre-aggregates it

Hello if you want to solve it using a case statement like you have tried, this is one way you can do it, but the solution is complicated, static in case we have 20, 30 AssignedLevels, it is not performant in case the table is very large, but this solution could be improved or it can gives you ideas for another way to solve it in case you face such problems in the future:
SELECT *,  
    COALESCE(
        CASE 
            WHEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN [assignedlevel] + 1 = 2 
                         AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE [manlevel02id] = p.[id])
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END = 1
            THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [manlevel02id] = 11111 THEN 1 END) OVER() 
            
            WHEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN [assignedlevel] + 1 = 3 
                         AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE [manlevel03id] = p.[id])
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END = 1
            THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [manlevel03id] = 22222 THEN 1 END) OVER() 
            
            WHEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN [assignedlevel] + 1 = 4 
                         AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE [manlevel04id] = p.[id])
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END = 1
            THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [manlevel04id] = 33333 THEN 1 END) OVER() 
            
            WHEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN [assignedlevel] + 1 = 5 
                         AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE [manlevel05id] = p.[id])
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END = 1
            THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [manlevel05id] = 66666 THEN 1 END) OVER()
        END, 0
    ) AS OrgCount
FROM YourTable p;

Here I unpivot the data but because we have nulls and Sql Server ignores nulls and we don't have the option to include nulls like in Oracle, I had to add it manually - the same this is static in case we have ManLevalId more then 20,30:
with data as (
select 
    id,
    assignedlevel,
    manlevel,
    manlevelid
from 
    (select 
        id, 
        assignedlevel, 
        manlevel02id, 
        manlevel03id, 
        manlevel04id, 
        manlevel05id 
     from YourTable 
    ) as sourcetable
unpivot
(
    manlevelid for manlevel in (manlevel02id, manlevel03id, manlevel04id, manlevel05id)
) as unpivotedtable
union all
select 
    id,
    assignedlevel,
    'manlevel02id' as manlevel,
    null as manlevelid
from YourTable 
where manlevel02id is null
union all
select 
    id,
    assignedlevel,
    'manlevel03id' as manlevel,
    null as manlevelid
from YourTable 
where manlevel03id is null
union all
select 
    id,
    assignedlevel,
    'manlevel04id' as manlevel,
    null as manlevelid
from YourTable 
where manlevel04id is null
union all
select 
    id,
    assignedlevel,
    'manlevel05id' as manlevel,
    null as manlevelid 
from YourTable 
where manlevel05id is null
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    d.id, 
    d.assignedlevel, 
    COUNT(d1.manlevelid) AS OrgCount
FROM 
    data d
LEFT JOIN 
    data d1 
    ON d.id = CASE 
        WHEN d.assignedlevel = 1 AND d1.manlevel = 'manlevel02id' THEN d1.manlevelid
        WHEN d.assignedlevel = 2 AND d1.manlevel = 'manlevel03id' THEN d1.manlevelid
        WHEN d.assignedlevel = 3 AND d1.manlevel = 'manlevel04id' THEN d1.manlevelid
        WHEN d.assignedlevel = 4 AND d1.manlevel = 'manlevel05id' THEN d1.manlevelid
    END 
GROUP BY 
    d.id, 
    d.assignedlevel, 
    d.manlevel, 
    d.manlevelid;

Hope it helps.
